# How do I unbind a Logitech G910 MR key

Tags: macros, keyboard, unbind, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have been having an issue with my F14 key ( M1G7 on Logitech G910 keyboard ) and even though I rebind the key, and do everything to try and locate where the keypresses are coming from, I can't find where the keys are being replayed from...

There are hundreds of keys pressed... It starts with ( Note up / down keypress unless down / up specified ) F3 down, Tab 4 times, Backspace, right, control down, q, control up, end, enter, r, e down, t, e up, u down, t up, r down, u up,n down, r up, n up, space, right shift down, -. right shift up, d, a, t, a, control down, b, control up then down, q, control up then down, b, control up then down, x, ... and it goes on for quite some time..

I have done a lot to try and figure it out...

- I have tried editing M1G7 in the software but nothing appears under multi-key - only my F14 bind.
- When I choose 'Test Profile' and press the M1G7 key, it says F14 pressed, delay, F14 released... It doesn't mention the hundreds or thousands of keys pressed. It doesn't mention the rebinded keys pressed. It doesn't mention anything.
- I have tried rebinding the key to F13, F15 and others which don't have the issue ( using M1G6, M1G8, etc.. ) and it doesn't matter - the M1G7 key still triggers the keys..
- I have tried unassigning M1G7 - the keys are still pressed ( Using different profiles, etc... it doesn't matter ).
- I have tried removing the F14 bind and recreating it from scratch with no luck ( I didn't expect it to because unassigning the key completely means the key still uses the MR bind )
- I have tried forcing profiles to be enabled, removing the default profile I use, etc... and it still remains.
- I have changed profiles in Logitech Gaming Software - the keys are still pressed when I press M1G7.
- I have tried deleting all profiles - the keys are still pressed when I press M1G7.
- I have tried using MR M1G7 MR, MR M1G7 ESCAPE MR, Holding MR Pressing M1G7 then tapping MR. I have tried MR M1G7 1234 MR..
- While the keys are updated, the updated macro never shows up in the software.
- I have ensured the latest Logitech Gaming Software was installed ( I had to update ) and I have performed all tests again with no change.

This is an incredibly annoying problem - even worse, some games will ban if they detect a mass amount of keys being pressed which amount to a macro even if it is built into the keyboard - but I have everything set for single keypresses anyway so I just want to reset the MR key and nothing on the G910 box says how to clear it, and as the bind doesn't show up in the software and as there is a default profile which is hidden which stores the MR binds and inaccessible I can't edit it manually.... Without a way to unset the MR bind, I'm up the creek... This leaves an entire set ( M1 ) of keys unusable so I don't accidentally press it and have my work deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is one answer - It may not be the best answer so I will not 'accept' it, but I will post it for anyone else having the same issue...

- Edit they MxGn key which is currently set, you may be able to create a throw-away key for this purpose...
- Select the Multi-Key option on the left
- Select Start Recording
- Press any key
- Select Stop Recording
- Click Ok or Save
- Delete the key ( or simply switch back to single-key option on the left ) OR RESTORE the original key back to the G key by dragging it to the G Key OR EDIT the key ( See next step )
- If Editing: Select Single Key, choose the key then click ok..
- If Deleting: Delete the key, then RESTORE a key ( or rebind )
- If Restoring or Rebinding: Drag a key from the list on the left side to the G Key with the appropriate M set selected.

Now, to test... Instead of using Test Profile as this will not work, open up a key, any key, from the left list by double-clicking it. Then, make sure you've selected the single-key selection ( you can also use the multi-key area and choose start recording, then press the key, then stop ) then press the G key you 'reset' and it should only show the key you want it to have - if it shows anything else, a step was performed incorrectly.... Make sure you do not save the key you're testing with - you can click Cancel or the X at the top right to ensure it isn't saved...

So, in short - simply edit multi-key, start recording, press a key, stop recording, save by clicking ok, reopen the key, switch to single key, specify the new key, click ok, then test... ( This should work, I used the sacrificial option by editing the key which was currently assigned, then deleting it and copying an identical key over from a different profile and all was fixed )..